# Can you compile Stockfish on Windows without Unix/GNU?

Tags: engines, stockfish, computer-chess

Can you compile Stockfish on Windows (without Unix/GNU), perhaps via Visual Studio?

The official "how to compile Stockfish on Windows" suggests using MinGW (see links below) and I am looking for a Windows-specific project build of Stockfish if it exists.

Links:

- [Compiling Stockfish on Windows](http://support.stockfishchess.org/kb/advanced-topics/compiling-stockfish-on-windows) (dead link, verified on 26.12.2020);
- [Compiling Stockfish yourself from the sources](https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish#compiling-stockfish-yourself-from-the-sources) (link added on 26.12.2020);
- [MinGW - Minimalist GNU for Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/).

Comment: Are you wanting to compile it, or are you wanting a version that runs on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stockfish source code can be easily compiled with gcc, Visual Studio, XCode etc. In Visual Studio, create an empty project, use the mouse to drag all files in Stockfish into the project then press the compile button. Very simple.

The only reason that Visual Studio is not listed in the documentation is that the website maintainer (Daylen Yang) is a Mac and Linux user. He doesn't have Windows installed so he didn't care about it.

Comment: Ah, very good. Thanks. The exclusion on the official "compile on Windows" page just had me suspicious.

Comment: I'll accept it, but I was actually going to try it out first to verify it (not questioning this doesn't work as it fits my initial thoughts). Wasn't trying to ignore your help! Thanks!

Comment: So I eventually tried this. Just now. With Visual C++ 2010 Express. And the compile fails. I dragged all the files in and compiled, and nothing more. I believe it could be the make file and incorporating those settings into it. I'll play around with it and see what I can figure out.

Comment: There seems to be a way to import the makefile into visual c++ 2010 express, but I have not figured it out yet. If anyone knows, let me know too!